# Renaming a file for upload

Tags: php, mysql, ios

I have been using a script for many years now for uploading photos to mysql. This has been verry useful for some time now, however it seems with ipads etc images uploaded all seem to be labelled with the same name "image". So when someone uploads 4 photos from their iphone it just gets overwritten because they have the same name. Can I modify my current script so that it renames photos to something unique or do I have to start from scratch again.?

```
 $target1 = "photo/"; 
 $target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['name']);
 $target2 = "photo/"; 
 $target2 = $target2 . basename( $_FILES['photo2']['name']);
 $target3 = "photo/"; 
 $target3 = $target3 . basename( $_FILES['photo3']['name']);
 $target4 = "photo/"; 
 $target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']);
```

thanks in  advance

Comment: Upload photo to MySQL ?! MySQL is a database, not a file server. And how is this piece of code relate to `mysql` and `ios` ?

Comment: With the blob data type it's not totally unreasonable, but I'll agree there are better options.

Comment: I suppose you could add a random number to the end of each photo's name using the php `explode` function.. though that wouldn't be very efficient because the number could overwrite itself

Comment: What about a time stamp?

Comment: Thanks Shivan I should have been more precise on that the script actually uploads the photos to a folder on my server, just the photo name goes into my sql for reference.

Comment: I'm thinking either the adding random number or time stamp option would suit. So do I just add this to my string?

    $target4 = $target4 . basename( $_FILES['photo4']['name']    ['time()']);

Comment: No that option dosen't work all I get is an ! as the photo name. On closer inspection that is just the first letter in the photo name.

Comment: @Ryan Sparks that would probably suit my needs as I only get a couple of these photos a week. I usually rename the photos every couple of days any way. Where would I find a tutorial on explode functions as this is a newbie to me.